# libmnl Issue while installing libnetfilter queue in linux

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to install libnetfilter_queue on Suse Linux. But after the 
`./configure` step it shows

> error: Package requirements (libmnl >= 1.0.3) were not met
>
> No package 'libmnl' found

I am new to Linux and all the solutions which are  available on the web, I don't know how to use them.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common problem to the people working in computer networking in linux environments.

Go to the below link and download the latest libmnl file.

> http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libmnl/downloads.html#libmnl-1.0.3

Unzip it using the below command

> tar -xvf libmnl-1.0.3.tar.bz2

cd to the extracted folder

> cd libmnl-1.0.3/

Install libmnl

> ./configure
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

Then you can install the libnetfilter_queue library.